# Is there a notepad that lets me change the background image?

Tags: text-editor, textedit

I want to put this blackboard as the background of my notepad, so when I type, it'll look like I'm writing on a blackboard.

Do you know a simple text editor that will let me use it as a background image?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WriteRoom](http://www.hogbaysoftware.com/products/writeroom) is a pretty awesome text editor in general, and will let you do this through its built in custom themes feature.

Answer (score 1):

[FocusWriter](http://gottcode.org/focuswriter/) is another text editor that will allow you to do this, and it is free.  However, it does not have as good of a design as WriteRoom does.